# C++ Case Switch printing to a Loop and stream to a file

Tags: c++

So I am working on a homework assignment and I have to create a Menu Driven Program to ask for how many repetitions I want for each loop type. I have most of the coding down and it prints to my file. I just don't know how to get it to be able to print how many numbers I want for each loop and to be able to put in dashes for when there is no number. For example if I chose only four numbers to be printed in my while loop, There would have to be 6 dashes for the rest of the box in my text file. I would really appreciate any advice or steps in the right direction. I also cannot use arrays because we haven't learned those in class yet.
[This is what my current program text file looks like with just loops.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HXne.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

ofstream ofs("J_Lab.txt");

// Global Variables
string myname = "Salvador J ";
string dat = "March 3 ";
string crnum = "CIS  ";
string lab = "Lab 5 ";
string sum = "Case Switch ";
string eof = "EOF MESSAGE ";
string lnu = "________________________________________"
"________________________________________";
string pipe = "|";
string lnu2 = "|_______________________________________"
"_______________________________________|";

// Variables for this program only
string wloop = "While";
string dwl = "Do";
string output = "LOOP Output for 3 different Looping mechanisms";
string frloop = "For";
string lnu3 = "|_______|______|______|______|______|"
"______|______|______|______|______|_______|";
string ttl = "Repitition selection for Looping";


//*****************************
//* Creates a Line with Pipes *
//*****************************

void pipefunc()
{
    ofs << lnu2 << endl;
}

//****************************
//*Creates another line with *
//* pipes running through it *
//****************************
void pipe2()

{
    ofs << lnu3 << endl;
}

//********************
//* HEADER            *
//********************
void hdr()
{
    ofs << lnu << endl;
    ofs << pipe
    << left << setw(20) << myname
    << left << setw(20) << dat
    << left << setw(20) << crnum
    << left << setw(18) << lab
    << pipe << endl;

}

//*********************************
//* Creates a box to explain what *
//* we are looking at             *
//*********************************
void box()
{
    ofs << lnu2 << endl;
    ofs << pipe
    << right << setw(60) << output
    << right << setw(19) << pipe << endl;
}

//*****************************
//* Summary of what's printed *
//*****************************
void ftr()
{
    ofs << pipe << left << setw(78) << sum << pipe << endl;

}

//***********************
//* End of File Message *
//***********************
void eoff()
{
    ofs << pipe
    << left << setw(15) << eof
    << left << setw(18) << myname
    << left << setw(12) << dat
    << left << setw(15) << crnum
    << left << setw(18) << lab
    << pipe << endl;
}

//***********
//* Menu    *
//***********

void menu()
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        cout << string(10, '\n');
        cout << string(5, '\t') << ttl << endl; // These will be variables
        cout << string(5, '\t') << "1. While Loop - How many?" << endl;
        cout << string(5, '\t') << "2. Do Loop    - How many?" << endl;
        cout << string(5, '\t') << "3. For Loop   - How many?" << endl;
        cout << string(5, '\t') << "4. Quit" << endl;


        cout << string(5, '\t') << "Enter a number between 1-4" << endl;
        cout << string(5, '\t');
        cin >> n;


        switch (n)
        {
            case 1: cout << "Inside case 1 === " << n << endl;
                break;
            case 2: cout << "Inside case 2 === " << n << endl;
                break;
            case 3: cout << "Inside case 3 === " << n << endl;
                break;
            case 4: cout << "We are out of here! === " << n << endl;
                break;
            default: cout << "Invalid data entry === " << n << endl;
                cout << "Must enter a number between 1-4" << endl;
        }
    } while (n != 4);

    system ("pause");
}


//***************
//* While Loop  *
//***************
void whl()
{

    ofs << pipe << left
    << setw (7) << wloop;
    int count;
    count = 1; // Initialize counter
    while (count <=10)
    {
        cout << count;
        ofs  << left << setw(6) << pipe << count;
        count++;
    }
    ofs << pipe << endl;

    menu();
}

int main()
{
    hdr();
    pipefunc();
    box();
    pipefunc();
    whl();
    pipe2();
    doo();
    pipe2();
    forr();
    pipe2();
    pipefunc();
    pipefunc();
    ftr();
    pipefunc();
    pipefunc();
    eoff();
    pipefunc();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: SO is for specific programming Q&A, not code review, guidance or mentoring. Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Welcome to SO.

Comment: Unrelated terminology: `count = 1; // Initialize counter` is an assignment, not an initialization. `int count = 1; // Initialize counter` is an initialization. Initialization can only be done when defining the variable or in a [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). Assignment can take a very different path than initialization and initialization often allows the compiler extra leeway in optimizing.

Comment: When you used a debugger, which statements are causing the issue?